# I need to enable a button when clicking Ctrl+A in table

Tags: java, keylistener

I am trying to enable a JButton when clicking "Ctrl+A" in a Jtable to select all rows, so I execute this code:

```
myTable.addKeyListener( new KeyListener() {         
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && ( e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK ) != 0 ) {  // User clicked (CTRL + A) in table.
            if( myTable.getRowCount() > 1 )
                myButton.setEnabled( true );
        }
    }               
});
```

The problem is that many times this does not work ... Every time all rows in table are selected fine, but the button is not enabled! I have to click "Ctrl+A" 3 or 4 times for this to work. Is there something about that I should know, or a better idea for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overridding `keyPressed` instead of `keyReleased`.

Comment: .. I should have thought more before asking ... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

> or a better idea for this to work ?

You should be using [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), not a KeyListener.